# Excel; copying refreshed daily values in each column/row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have one Excel file, two work sheets. In one work sheet I imported daily FX rates database through web query that refreshes daily when I open it (worksheet A).  In the other worksheet (worksheet B) I would like to present values of only certain FX rates on a daily basis.

The question is, how can I simplify things by making a shortcut that automatically copies the data from worksheet A to worksheet B? The problem I am having is that of course, I can copy the cell but I can’t just drag it down for all the dates because in that case, everytime the databse in worksheet A refreshes all the columns take the same value (of the refreshed todays value).

[Course 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIXGt.png)

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klfzg.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Worksheet A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNLd3.png)
[Worksheet B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX4IT.png)

I just saw that in the previous 2 pictures I uploaded, worksheet A and B are mistakenly named. To sum up: worksheet A is the daily refreshed database from web page, worksheet B is the active work sheet to which I am trying to copy daily values from worksheet A.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
First get rid of the space in the sheet names and rename your Sheets Worksheet A & B to WorksheetA and WorksheetB respectively. Then copy the following formula =INDEX(WorksheetA!$E$6:$E$36,MATCH(B$1,WorksheetA!$C$6:$C$36,1)) and paste it to WorksheetB!B32. You can then drag that formula across to E32. You can also prefill the range WorksheetB!B33:E... of future dates with that formula.
Copy the range WorksheetB!B32:E32 and paste it on itself using Values only.
That should dot the trick

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. I tried it and the first first column works like a charm (B32). But when I drag the formula to E32 the rest of the values are not correct (they take different fx rates and not the proper ones). Any idea why?

Comment: It works now because I switched the "1" in the formula with "0". But I don't understand how this will take care of the main issue; tomorrow when the database refreshes won't it override the value?

Comment: Once you updated today s range of cells, select the range, copy and paste "special" using values.

Comment: Make sure your formulae for subsequent days are not erased in the process. I should encourage you to use an alternate  simpler method which would consists of using the cell naming features of excel.

Answer (score 0):

In Sheets B at appropriate place positions cell pointer & write this

```
=Vlookup (SheetB! F2, SheetA! $A$2:$E$36,2,FALSE)
```

F2 has current date to Match.

In addition do this

1. Click a cell in the external data range.
2. On the Data tab, in the Connections group, click the arrow next to Refresh, and then click Connection Properties .
3. Click the Usage tab.
4. Under Refresh control, select the Refresh data when opening the file check box.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work, I don't understand what the "F2" is suppose to be?

Comment: Hey Jake97, 
in my example cell F2 hold the Current date,, so that every morning after download the data you can pull it into Sheet B,, Current date is the Key to Pull Current data & then follow refresh Manually as I've suggested or Create VBA.

Answer (score -1):

from your description of the issue it seems that you would need to implement the functions INDEX MATCH in combination to update sheet A with the values of sheet B, using  date as the key. It might be helpful if you post the relevant columns of each sheet, to clarify your question.

Comment: Hello,here are the columns

Comment: Please post sheet B Column E. Also, do you copy using the fill handle feature of Excel? See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db

Comment: Regarding sheet B column E; these values are all hand written because like I said, unfortunately I can't copy them by using worksheet A, because everytime the data in worksheet A refreshes it overrides the value.

Comment: Think of the two sheets as two tables (as in database tables). If you want to update Sheet B using Sheet A data, you need to establish a common column in both sheets (similar to a database key). Since you're not showing Sheet B I cannot really comment further, but the basic idea is to implement a common column (either date or FX currency code) in BOTH sheets and set up the column-to-be-updated of sheet B using INDEX / MATCH functions.

Comment: Hi, I've uploaded sheet B in my second anwser.

Comment: sorry, i had missed that. one moment...

Comment: see new answer above

Comment: If you WorksheetB FX column headers never change (CAD,CHF,SEK,HRK), then another easier solution would be to use fixed cell addressing as follows: in WorksheetB!A32, type WorksheetA!$E$23, and so on for each FX code. Then copy/paste onto itself using Values only option.